# Error trapping within custom function: TypeError still prints as an error despite being accounted for within function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a custom function, and I am trying to do some error-trapping within a custom function with the idea of printing more user-friendly error messages as opposed to the bulky, somewhat intimidating-looking error blocks.

Here is my data and custom function:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'col1':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'],
        'foo':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
        'bar':[8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
        'foobar':[15,16,17,18,19,20,21]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

#Function
def func(a, b, c, d):
    """
    Parameters
    ---------------
    a = String
        name of col 2 in data frame
    b = String
        name of col 3 in data frame
    c = String
        name of col 4 in data frame
    d = String
        Name of last desired output column
        
    Returns:
    ---------------
    Input data frame with appended columns
    
    Example:
    ---------------
    func('foo', 'bar', 'foobar', lastcol)
    """
    try:
        df['new_col1'] = df[a] + 44
        df['new_col2'] = df[b] + 88
        df['new_col3'] = df[c] + 133
        
        if d is not None:
            df[d] = df[a] + df[b]
        
        return df.head(5)
        
    except NameError:
        print('Input parameter(s) likely entered wrong.')
    
    except TypeError as err:
        print({}.format(err))
        print('No input parameters can be blank.')
        
    except KeyError:
        print('KeyError: At least one input does not follow the input format. Type ?func to see examples.')
```

The KeyError works as expected, as misspelling one of the arguments `func('fo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'lastcol')` produces the following message in plain text:

```
KeyError: At least one input does not follow the input format. Type ?func to see examples.
```

However, when leaving a parameter blank `func(a = 'foo', b = 'bar', d = 'lastcol')`, the traditional error block is thrown even though I have included a `TypeError` in my `try-except` block.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [36], in <module>
----> 1 func(a = 'fo', b = 'bar', d = 'lastcol')

TypeError: func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'
```

How can I fix this so the entire error block is not thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TypeError` is thrown before `func` is actually called. A solution would be to wrap `func` in a second function and inside it call `func`:

```
def func(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    Parameters
    ---------------
    a = String
        name of col 2 in data frame
    b = String
        name of col 3 in data frame
    c = String
        name of col 4 in data frame
    d = String
        Name of last desired output column
        
    Returns:
    ---------------
    Input data frame with appended columns
    
    Example:
    ---------------
    func('foo', 'bar', 'foobar', lastcol)
    """
    try:
        def _func(a, b, c, d):
            """
            The real function.
            """
            df['new_col1'] = df[a] + 44
            df['new_col2'] = df[b] + 88
            df['new_col3'] = df[c] + 133
            
            if d is not None:
                df[d] = df[a] + df[b]
            
            return df.head(5)
            
        _func(*args, **kwargs)
    except NameError:
        print('Input parameter(s) likely entered wrong.')
    
    except TypeError as err:
        print('{}'.format(err))
        print('No input parameters can be blank.')
        
    except KeyError:
        print('KeyError: At least one input does not follow the input format. Type ?func to see examples.')
```

Testing:

```
>>> func(a = 'fo', b = 'bar', d = 'lastcol')
_func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'
No input parameters can be blank.
```